# Integrating stripe-payments into pin scaffolding using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to integrate stripe payments into my pin scaffolding (RoR) and currently get the following error.

Here is the following error message below and it highlights "@pin = Pin.find(params[:id])":

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PinsController#show

 private
     def set_pin
     @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
 end

    def correct_user
```

Here are my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :pins

  devise_for :users
  root "pins#index"
  get "about" => "pages#about" #creates about_path
  get "contact" => "pages#contact" #creates contact_path
  get "auction" => "pages#auction" #creates auction_path
  get "terms" => "pages#terms" #creates terms_path
  post 'send_mail', to: 'contact#send_mail'
  get 'contact', to: 'contact#show'

  scope 'pins', controller: :pins do
    scope '/:id' do
     post 'bid', to: :bid
    end
  end

  scope 'admin', controller: :admin do
    scope 'pins' do
      get '/:pin_id', to: :pin
    end
 end
end
```

How do I resolve this issue and get started on the right path?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What route are you hitting? If it's the admin route, you've set the route to pass the parameter as `pin_id` not `id`. So change your route that is currently

```
get '/:pin_id', to: :pin
```

to

```
get '/:id', to: :pin
```

Or change your controller to look for `params[:pin_id]`.

Comment: Thanks Mike!  I just tried changing the routes to what you suggested but still run into the same error message where it "Couldn't find Pin with 'id'=receipt"  for  @ pin = Pin.find(params[:id]) at the controller.  Just to be clear, are you suggesting I just change it to: @ pin = Pin.find(params[:pin_id] instead?

Comment: For  "@pin = Pin.find(params[:id])" at the controller, I just  changed it to: "@pin = Pin.find(params[:pin_id]" and get "SyntaxError in PinsController#index" unexpected keyword end, even though the syntax looks right.  What could be wrong here?

Comment: You didn't close your parenthesis.

Comment: At this point I'm getting: "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PinsController#show" for "@pin = Pin.find(params[:pin_id])", would I simply just add a new method to this controller?  Since I currently have a show method in place currently showing existing bids: 
def show
    @existing_bid = @pin.bid_for(current_user)
  end